# What programs can I use to burn a Windwos 7 iso on a USB?

Tags: 12.04, windows-7, live-usb, iso

WinUSB keeps on freezing. Unetbootin doesn't work, and neither does Tuxboot. I'm running Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/289559/how-to-create-a-windows-8-bootable-usb-stick-with-ubuntu

Comment: and http://askubuntu.com/questions/116885/can-i-use-ubuntu-to-write-a-windows-7-iso-to-usb-in-ubuntu

Comment: It's first time when I here that someone wants to burn something on a USB. I don't think that it's possible...

Comment: @Fischer All it suggests is WinUSB, and Unetbootin. Neither of them work.

Answer (score 0):

Try YUMI. It creates bootable pen drives using an iso image 
http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/

Comment: When I download it, and open it in Software Center, I can't download it. It has a error.

Comment: @Shadoww what's the error? when no software works on your pc, then the problem is probably has to do with your pc not the software itself