# How to create an .iso image from a windows dvd that i can then put on a flash-drive

Tags: live-usb, iso, dvd

Here is what I have:

- a Windows 7 AIO DVD that is already bootable
- no CD rom
- a flash drive
- empty DVDs

I only get computers with cd-roms a few times a week.

Here is what I want to do:

- make a bootable iso file out of the dvd
- copy the iso file onto my computer and make a live usb for windows using winusb
- using the same iso, create a new dvd with windows on it so that if i lose one of them, I will have a spare one

So I need help with creating the iso from the DVD and I can do the rest easily. but i want the iso to be bootable and installable to a flash drive.

Comment: This has anything to do with Ubuntu/Linux?

Comment: To the extent to which this question is on-topic here (i.e., related to Ubuntu), this seems to be answered in [How can I create a Windows bootable USB stick with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/289559/22949) and [Can I use Ubuntu to write a Windows 7 ISO to USB?](https://askubuntu.com/q/116885/22949)

Answer (score 0):

Although I do not understand what this question has to do with Ubuntu or Linux, I will give you some pointers.

If you are using Ubuntu you can use Brasero which is pre-installed in Ubuntu or you can download [dvd-rip](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/dvdrip/). If you are using windows, you can extract boot image from CD/DVD using [WinISO](http://www.winiso.com/support/tutorials/extract-boot-image.html) or [MagicISO](http://www.magiciso.com/support.htm) (there must be plenty others). You can use the same tools to make copies of bootable CD/DVDs. Once you have the image you can make a live USB with this image using [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Only answer where Ubuntu or a supported derivative is used is valid.

Comment: @Ron WinISO seems great, but i am not using windows. Is there a WinISO alternative for ubuntu

Comment: @KidusAmare I suggest you mention that you are using Ubuntu in your OP. If you are using KDE, try [Kiso](http://kiso.sourceforge.net/). Brasero, which is pre-installed in Ubuntu should also work.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use `usb-creator-gtk` or `usb-creator-common`. To install:

```
sudo apt-get install usb-creator-gtk
```

I've used it to create various installation CD/DVD's from many Linux distros (although Windows is also possible).

Answer (score 0):

> I need help with creating the iso from the DVD and I can do the rest
>   easily

To create an iso image from a DVD

```
dd if=/dev/cdrom of=image_name.iso
```

Replace `/dev/cdrom` with the path of your drive, if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

To make a `.iso` image out of a DVD you can just insert the DVD in the drive and run the following command:

```
sudo dd if=<dvd_drive_block_device> of=<path_to_iso>
```

Where `<dvd_drive_block_device>` is the DVD drive's block device as reported by `lsblk`, and where `<path_to_iso>` is the path to the `.iso` file that you want to create.

Also to make a bootable USB out of the `.iso` image, you can run:

```
sudo dd if=<path_to_iso> of=<usb_drive_block_device>
```

Where `<path_to_iso>` is the path to the `.iso` file that you created, and where `<usb_drive_block_device>` is the USB drive's block device as reported by `lsblk`.

Also if you want to create a bootable USB out of a DVD directly, you can combine these two methods in a one-liner:

```
sudo dd if=<dvd_drive_block_device> of=<usb_drive_block_device>
```

Where `<dvd_drive_block_device>` is the DVD drive's block device as reported by `lsblk`, and where `<usb_drive_block_device>` is the USB drive's block device as reported by `lsblk`.