# USB windows install going all wrong

Tags: boot, partitioning, usb, mount

[Can I use Ubuntu to write a Windows 7 ISO to USB?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/116885/can-i-use-ubuntu-to-write-a-windows-7-iso-to-usb)

pointed me in the right direction! (close this if you like)

Im trying to reinstall windows through a usb drive and remove ubuntu 14.04

My disks readout is

Size : 8.0 GB — 7.9 GB free (1.1% full)

Device : /dev/sdb1

Partition type : HPFS/NTFS (Bootable)

Contents : NTFS — Mounted at /media/f-17/bullshit

This is where I stand now, Ive tried unetbootin (After pushing OK imgur.com/6BQhtow) there is most definitely a USB drive in a working USB slot, and gparted returns in terminal

```
======================
libparted : 2.3
======================

(gpartedbin:10708): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 7 was not found when attempting to remove it

(gpartedbin:10708): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 6 was not found when attempting to remove it

(gpartedbin:10708): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 26 was not found when attempting to remove it

(gpartedbin:10708): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 25 was not found when attempting to remove it
Input/output error during read on /dev/mmcblk0
```

and then when it opens gives the following error after thinking a while

Window title : Libparted bug found!

Error : Input/output error during read on /dev/mmcblk0

My mount options are set to this : imgur.com/RHyQaw8

Comment: "/bullshit" Just say it, not replace it with "bullshit"

Comment: thats the name i gave the drive I can change it should this site require me to...